# How many way to arrange seven men on ten chairs?

Tags: combinatorics

We have $7$ men and $10$ seats, in how many different way is possible to arrange the $7$ man on the chairs under the condition that no two empty chairs are adiacent?

This is my solution:

The total amount of permutations without the condition is:

$$10!$$

Just permute all, this will include adjacent and not adjacent chairs without distinction.

No i will remove some permutation in order to fullfill the condition! If i consider all the three seats as a single entity, and remove them from my count i have:

$$10!-8!$$

Seven men plus one big chair (the tree chairs as a single entity)

Now I should remove all the paired (two chairs) chairs from my count, i must be sure that the third chair is not adjacent to the pair, to account for this situation i must consider the following cases:

1. The pair of chairs is at the extreme border of the row
2. The pair of chairs is somewhere in the middle of the row

In the first case the amount of permutation allowed is:

$$2{3 \choose 2}{7 \choose 1}7!$$

Two border, a group of $2$ chairs from the $3$ possible then one boy from the $7$ available and finally the other boys and the chair permuted.

For the second case, i need to put $2$ boys near the chair,so:

$$7{3 \choose 2}{7 \choose 2}6!$$

Where $7$ are the possible position for the group of chairs plus the boys.

So the final count is:

$$10!-8!-2{3 \choose 2}{7 \choose 1}7!-7{3 \choose 2}{7 \choose 2}6!$$

Which is $2318316$.

Does this make any sense?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that you have solved this as if you have numbered the empty chairs, i.e swapping two of the empty chairs gives 'another solution' that you have counted. This comes from the term ${3 \choose 2}$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way: Lay out $7$ chairs in a row, with space between them, and seat the people. This can be done in $7!$ ways.

We have now $8$ "gaps" (including the endgaps) to slide empty chairs into, one chair per gap. There are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to do this, for a total of $7!\binom{8}{3}$.

Note that this answer is (numerically) not the same as yours. However, your final numerical computation is not correct.

If we are not interested in who sits where, just which chairs will be occupied and which will not, the answer is simply $\binom{8}{3}$.